# mongolab request returning empty find results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web

I have a website that is accessing a local node.js server (that accesses a mongolab database), but when I use a front-end function to request a user JSON object, the mongo database returns nothing. (JSON.parse() finds an unexpected end of data at line 1 col 1)

Here is the front-end function that requests the user data by email and password:

```
function requestUser(email, password) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888/getUser/" + email + "/" + password, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           user = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
           console.log(user);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here is the node.js express server (back-end):

```
 var http = require("http"),
    mongojs = require("mongojs"),
    express = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    fs = require("fs"),
    url = require("url");

app = express();
app.use(cors());

var uri = "mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds036698.mongolab.com:36698/alirodatabase";
var db = mongojs(uri, ["Papers", "Users"]);

app.get('/getUser/:email/:passwd', function(req, res, next) {
  var users = db.Users.find({"email": req.params.email,
                            "password": req.params.passwd});
  user = users.toArray[0];
  res.json(user);
});

app.listen(8888, function() {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 8888');
});
```

EDIT 1:

```
app.get('/getUser/:email/:passwd', function(req, res, next) {
    var user = db.Users.findOne({
        "email": req.params.email,
        "password": req.params.passwd
    }, function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({error: 'error retrieving the JSON user' });
            }
            else {
                res.json(doc);
            }
    });
});
```

I added async functionality to the nodeserver, but now I am receiving the err: "error retrieving the JSON user". Is this a problem that could be solved by hosting my own database and not using mongolab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the docs for mongojs (https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs). You're not using callbacks at all. The functions don't `return` values because it's Javascript/Node.js where things like to be async. So you have to use callbacks to handle the results. The idea is "find these documents" and then some time later when it actually gets the documents "do something with the documents".

```
app.get('/getUser/:email/:passwd', function(req, res, next) {
    var users = db.Users.find({
        "email": req.params.email,
        "password": req.params.passwd
    }, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            //handle the error
            res.json({error: ':(' });
        }
        else {
            docs.toArray(function(err, users) {
                if (err)  {
                    //handle the error
                    res.json({error: ':(' });
                }
                else {
                    res.json(users[0]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Lastly, I'd recommend using `findOne` rather than `find`. Then you won't need to use `toArray` to get a single document because it's returned as a single document in the first callback.

Comment: Can you look at the EDIT above?

Comment: why am I getting the error? (I am now using findOne())

Comment: You'd have to read `err` and see what it says. Just use `console.log(err)` to write the error to the console.